# php sort multi array by order value

Tags: php, arrays

Can someone give me a solution how to sort the multi array by order number?

```
$data['submain'][ 44 ][0] = array(
        'title'=> 'title',
        'order' => 2
);  

$data['submain'][ 44 ][1] = array(
        'title'=> 'title 2',
        'order' => 1
);

$data['submain'][ 44 ][2] = array(
        'title'=> 'title F',
        'order' => 5
);

$data['submain'][ 44 ][3] = array(
        'title'=> 'title F',
        'order' => 2
);

foreach ($data['submain'] as $page_id => $page ){

  usort($data['submain'][$page_id], function($a, $b) {
    return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
  });

  //echo '<pre>';
  //print_r($data['submain']);
}
```

Comment: and what is the *order number*? 44,22,33,11 or 0,1,2,3?  what output will you aproche? who build the $data-array?

Answer (score 0):

thought it would good to share the solution :)

```
$output = [];

foreach ($data['submain'] as $page_id => $page ){
  usort($page, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
  });
  $output[$page_id] = $page;
}

$data['submain'] = $output;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data['submain']);
```